# tests msr not displaying in SonarQube API

Tags: sonarqube

I have SonarQube set up for all of our repositories. On most of these everything works - coverage, tests, lines covered etc. shows up in the api call. For some (maybe 1/4), the tests msr does not show. See examples below.

One interesting note:  in the cases where the tests msr does not show, coverage is still calculated correctly.

Do I have something not set up right? Is this a problem in Sonar or in Jacoco?

Here's my uri for both examples:

http://buildbox:9000/api/resources?metrics=lines_to_cover,uncovered_lines,coverage,tests

Good:

```
{
  "id": 62,
  "key": "com.blah.source",
  "name": "source",
  "scope": "PRJ",
  "qualifier": "TRK",
  "date": "2016-12-09T14:18:43-0700",
  "creationDate": "2014-11-19T14:54:59-0700",
  "lname": "source",
  "version": "3.2.4.0",
  "description": "The main module for the Blah Site.",
  "msr": [
    {
      "key": "tests",
      "val": 707,
      "frmt_val": "707"
    },
    {
      "key": "coverage",
      "val": 2.8,
      "frmt_val": "2.8%"
    },
    {
      "key": "lines_to_cover",
      "val": 256213,
      "frmt_val": "256,213"
    },
    {
      "key": "uncovered_lines",
      "val": 248879,
      "frmt_val": "248,879"
    }
  ]
}
```

Bad:

```
{
  "id": 27115,
  "key": "com.blah.client:client",
  "name": "client",
  "scope": "PRJ",
  "qualifier": "TRK",
  "date": "2016-10-05T15:17:27-0600",
  "creationDate": "2015-08-14T15:01:36-0600",
  "lname": "best-match-client",
  "version": "1.0.47",
  "description": "Base POM: contains testing dependencies, testing profile, and simple build",
  "msr": [
    {
      "key": "coverage",
      "val": 97.7,
      "frmt_val": "97.7%"
    },
    {
      "key": "lines_to_cover",
      "val": 418,
      "frmt_val": "418"
    },
    {
      "key": "uncovered_lines",
      "val": 7,
      "frmt_val": "7"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is "tests msr"?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I guess that "msr" = measure.

Comment: JaCoCo is about Code Coverage, not about tests. And since you can see coverage I guess that this has nothing to do with JaCoCo.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam please see the example - it's the msr object, which contains an array of objects containing key/val/frmt_val - one of the keys when this is working correctly is "tests", which according to your documentation is the number of tests in the maven repo.

Comment: @Godin since the problem could be in Jacoco or in Sonar, I felt it was appropriate to put both tags on, so that other people with the same issue can find this question. Is that against the rules or something? I can't keep track of all the SO rules, and people seem to come in and edit things indiscriminately and inconsistently.

Comment: I believe the count of tests comes from the test execution data. Are you sure you're providing it in the 1/4th of projects in question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "providing it" - I am getting the code coverage measurements, so obviously the code is instrumented and the tests are running. Would be great if I'm doing something wrong though, because that means I can fix it!

Comment: @orbfish As a JaCoCo developer I can tell that inability of SonarQube to show information about tests is unrelated to JaCoCo library that only measures coverage - JaCoCo did its job perfectly since you can see coverage results. You can also confirm that JaCoCo has no effect on your problem here by disabling/removing JaCoCo. Hence to not confuse people, I proposed to removed tag.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam any thoughts? You seem to be my only hope on this.

Comment: @Godin You're probably right. Is there any way to verify in the jacoco data that all is well with number of tests? I don't see any indication in the html that indicates number of tests. I could check this in one of the working repos against one of the non-working repos. Thanks!

Comment: @orbfish once again JaCoCo is solely about coverage. It has no connection with tests and can measure coverage of any execution of Java application, even manual. That's why you won't find inside of JaCoCo data/reports any metric about tests, and that's why your issue is unrelated to JaCoCo. Information about tests is provided by test executors. For example in case of Maven it is usually maven-surefire-plugin.

Comment: Thanks @Godin that gives me something to track down.